# Swift5 Play aac file AvAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, audio, compression, avaudiosession

I currently play a wav file with the code below. But now i have compressed the files to aac-files and i can't figure out how to play them? I tried to change the withExtension to "aac" instead but no sound. Any ideas?

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "aac") else { return }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.ac3.rawValue)
        audioPlayer.volume = currentVolume
        newAudioPlayer.audioPlayer.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to play AAC files you can use AVAudioEngine audio player node:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "audio_name", withExtension: "aac")!
        do {
            let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
            guard let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFile.processingFormat, frameCapacity: .init(audioFile.length)) else { return }
            try audioFile.read(into: buffer)
            audioEngine.attach(player)
            audioEngine.connect(player, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: buffer.format)
            try audioEngine.start()
            player.play()
            player.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .loops)

        } catch {
               print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I using for aac format I found "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" for the url. But its works for the wav, mp3 formats.

Comment: Make sure your file is included in your bundle

Comment: I added the .aac file. And 100% sure about this. But failed to figure out the problem

Comment: @YJunction if `Bundle.main.url` method returns nil your file is not included in your bundle.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I did a little mistake. I copied the aac file but it's not included in my bundle. Now I included it from target>Build Phases>Bundle Resources>Click '+'  And now it's working fine.